# I will outlast all, what am I?

Tags: riddle

I cannot be moved although you may move through me.

You cannot hold me, but you can easily show me.

Fast or slow, my speed will never changed.

I will outlast all, at least until all are gone.

Comment: My debt, clearly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Time?

I cannot be moved although you may move through me.

> One cannot move the time, but it goes by anyway.

You cannot hold me, but you can easily show me.

> You can show the time - like on a clock dial.

Fast or slow, my speed will never changed.

> Speed of time cannot be changed.

I will outlast all, at least until all are gone.

> After all are gone, the time will still go on.

Comment: your explanation for "Fast or slow, my speed will never changed." is wrong. The speed of "your answer here" is not fixed.

Comment: @Marius, I don't get it, what has the speed of "my answer here" to do with this line?

Comment: I used "your answer here" as placeholder for your answer. I didn't want to spoil it for other readers. Replace "your answer here" with your answer to the riddle and read again.

Comment: @Marius In this case I have to disagree with you. The speed of time can change only relatively to an observer but from a subjective point of view it will remain constant.

Comment: I don't understand how it is possible to move through time. Did I miss the invention of a time machine?

Comment: Explanation of why this was the answer i was looking for: 

I cannot be moved although you may move through me- Obvious enough

You cannot hold me, but you can show me- Intangible but you can show the effects

Fast or slow speed never changed- this has more to do with perception... ex Time flies when you're having fun.. but the actual 'speed' of time doesn't change

Outlast all, at least until all are gone- more philosophical as in: if no one is around to observe it, would time exists? Because of the nature of that idea, we can at least say time will last so long as there are observers

Comment: @WaKai You're moving through time right now... time is passing by... tick-tock - tick-tock

Comment: @MegaMark My understanding of time is, that I am moving _with_ the time. Could be that english is not my native language.

Comment: @WaKai I wouldn't necessarily disagree... on a scientific level... but I hope at least that you can appreciate that this is a riddle, not to taken to the level of detail that science can provide, but more as a general "the-clue-fits"... no, you're not wrong, but the realm of a simple riddle... I mean... c'mon...

Comment: I thought time until your third hint, which isn't true for time. In fact I thought it was a dead giveaway for @WaKai's answer, light.

Comment: I will admit, only after the post did I think of more clues to help. And I will admit (and by the voting score- it seems to be the general consensus that...) @WaKai 's answer is not only fitting, but favored over the answer I was looking for. However, I cannot bring myself to fancy the idea of changing the answer from what I was actually going for, to another very well (if not better) suited answer because it just wouldn't be ethical. I praise that answer, +1 and 10/10... If anything I should be faulted for not trying to answer my own riddle before posting it to make certain this kind of...

Comment: collision would not occur. Again, I don't disagree with what you've said. But the answer I had in mind for the riddle lies in answer above provided by @RadoslavHristov

Comment: How do you show time? Time is not physical and something that's not physical cannot reflect or emit light, so we cannot see it.

Comment: @Stephan Bijzitter You are taking the riddle too scientifically. It's a riddle, not a theory of time.

Answer (score 22):

You are

> light

I cannot be moved although you may move through me.

> You can't move light, but we move everyday through the sunlight

You cannot hold me, but you can easily show me.

> It is impossible to hold/touch the light because the photons got no mass. It is easily to show light as the absence of darkness.

Fast or slow, my speed will never changed.

> Speed of light is always constant => c

I will outlast all, at least until all are gone.

> There will be always light somewhere in the universe. So as long as life remains there will be light.

Comment: Wow, this was great!!!   
I had a different answer in mind... but definite kudos and +1 for this

Comment: But certainly one can move light, for example by turning on a flashlight.

Comment: And I just had a coworker bring up the fact that you can manipulate light by bending (prism) and (this part is hearsay only... I have no valid research to back up the next statement) apparently 'scientists' have successfully completed  an experiment in which they slowed the speed of light <--- I really don't know about that... doesn't sound legit... but IF he's right than this answer doesn't fit any better than the accepted one... Although I still ultimately like it better... I hate when I has the dumb

Comment: @MegaMark: Light travelling different speeds in different substances is what causes refraction.  Snell's Law describes this, and the index of refraction *n* in any substance is exactly the ratio by which speed is slowed, compared to light's speed in a vaccuum.

Comment: @BenVoigt yeah... coworker suggested that this experiment I have no other knowledge or evidence of, was done without refraction... again it's more than fishy to me

Comment: `c` is the speed of light *in a vacuum.* I understand its speed can and does vary in other media.

Comment: Why is there only light as long as there is life? Stars will still "shine" even if no one can see them.

Comment: @MegaMark Everything is fine, don't worry. I am here for the fun, not to collect green ticks.

Answer (score 10):

> Easy, a doorway :D

I cannot be moved although you may move through me.

> self-explanatory

You cannot hold me, but you can easily show me.

> Yup, you can hold a door, but not a doorway. As for showing where it is, there's no problem.

Fast or slow, my speed will never changed.

> Obviously it won't, because it's static.

I will outlast all, at least until all are gone.

> The doorway will silently and haughtily let anyone through and yet stay still, as long as the door is opened. Even after the doorway isn't used anymore it could still remain in place for some time (or could not in case of building demolition, but this doesn't really matter already).

Comment: I love this out of the box explanation.  +1 for you sir

Answer (score 3):

> The Universe

I  cannot be moved although you may move through me.

> You cannot move it because everything you move is relative to space. But the universe is the space.

You cannot hold me, but you can easily show me.

> You cannot hold the universe, but you can view it / show it (well, part of it) using different tools or with the naked eye.

Fast or slow, my speed will never changed.

> Again, speed is relative to something and since the universe is everything....its speed is 0.

I will outlast all, at least until all are gone.

> According to the [Big Freeze Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_of_an_expanding_universe) the universe will expand and get colder until the there is no life left, or even possible.

Comment: Very good answer... but not what I was looking for... +1

Answer (score 3):

> MACRO (#defined) :D

I cannot be moved although you may move through me.

> Its Read Only

You cannot hold me, but you can easily show me.

> Can not have a pointer to it (me thinks :P), can be copied to a variable and shown

Fast or slow, my speed will never changed.

> Constant Location in the Read Only segment promises a constant access time (sans calculations and operations :D)

I will outlast all, at least until all are gone.

> Has a global scope and life till program end, when all variables are released.

Comment: A typo: it's `#define`, not `#defined`.

Answer (score 1):

> It is River

I cannot be moved although you may move through me.

> That's right, nobody can move it just change in path by altering its course but you can easily pass through it.

You cannot hold me, but you can easily show me

> Can't be contained(unless dam), but you can show its reflection or show by  >! its activity like rock cutting, erosion etc

Fast or slow, my speed will never changed.

> Fast during heavy rain or slow during drought like condition, but it is perennial maintaining its natural speed

I will outlast all, at least until all are gone

> From ages it is there and will be there, until all its attributes rain or snow is gone (that will happen when everything finished)!>

Comment: Not an "in-the-box-answer"... I like it.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was a little more poetic :)

I think it could also be

> Love

I cannot be moved although you may move through me.

> People who are in love would almost move anywhere (to get to teir beloved person)

You cannot hold me, but you can easily show me.

> Love is not something you can hold (i.e. a material) but you can show love to other people

Fast or slow, my speed will never changed.

> Love is always instant (at least for me it is)

I will outlast all, at least until all are gone.

> (For the sake of the "perfect world") If you love somebody, you wont stop loving them, until you / they dont live anymore